# Evaluating clojure function to a quoted form

Tags: list, macros, clojure, clojurescript

I am using a function that takes arguments as follows:
    `(test-function '((gate 1) (gate 3) (gate 2)))`

The list argument can contain any number of elements where each element is of the form `(gate x)` where `x` can be an integer from 0 to 8. I have a function, `generate-gate-list`, that generates lists of random length (up to 10) and content, although they are ALWAYS of the form above.

Example output of generate-gate-list: `((gate 2))`, `(())`, `((gate 1) (gate 6))`, etc.

I would like to be able to nest `generate-gate-list` inside `test-function` so that I can test a bunch of randomly generated lists without generating them all beforehand. In other words, I'd like something like this: `(test-function '(generate-gate-list))` except where generate-gate-list has been evaluated. I've tried some sort of macro syntax-quote and unquoting, but that leads to resolved variables, like `(user/gate 3)` which screws up test-function. Here's my generate-gate-list code:

```
(defn generate-gate-list []
  (map symbol (repeatedly (rand-int 10) #(random-gate))))
```

`random-gate` outputs a gate element as a string, i.e `"(gate 3)"` or `"(gate 2)"`.

So in short, I'd like `(test-function (something-here (generate-gate-list)))` or `(test-function (modified-generate-gate-list))` to be equivalent to `(test-function '((gate 1) (gate 4) (gate 2)))` or some other arbitrary output of generate-gate-list. Thanks!

Comment: Is `gate` a function? If so, what does it do?

Comment: `gate` is a function, but I can't modify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Quoting Produces Literal Lists

I believe your confusion is thinking that quoting is the only way to produce a list. While quoting can produce a literal list as in `'((gate 1) (gate 2))`, as you've likely discovered, nothing inside the list gets evaluated. Therefore, you can't produce a random list in this fashion, as your random variable will not be evaluated.

### Symbol Produces Only Symbols

Invoking `symbol` on a text representation of a list "(gate 1)" as you are doing in your `generate-gate-list` function, does not work. It produces a symbol that looks like a list, not a list.

```
user=> (type (symbol "(gate 1)"))
clojure.lang.Symbol
```

### Lists are created with `list`

If you want evaluation to occur, i.e. to populate your lists with variables, use the `list` function.

```
user=> (list 'gate 1)
(gate 1)

user=> (list 'gate (rand-int 10))
(gate 2)
```

---

### Example

Not knowing what your `test-function` is, let's just do this

```
(defn test-function 
  [gate-list]
  "Turn a list of (gate n) pairs into a list of gate numbers" 
  (map second gate-list))
```

---

```
user=> (test-function '((gate 1) (gate 2)))
(1 2)
```

---

```
(defn generate-gate-list []
  (repeatedly (rand-int 10) #(list 'gate (rand-int 10))))

user=> (def a-random-list (generate-gate-list))
#'user/a-random-list

user=> a-random-list
((gate 2) (gate 5) (gate 2) (gate 8) (gate 4))

user=> (test-function a-random-list)
(2 5 2 8 4)
```